# why does Cross Validation *not* solve Backtest overfitting?

Tags: backtesting, sharpe-ratio, model-validation

In this [famous paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2460551), Bailey and De Prado discard Cross Validation as tool to check for Backtest overfitting, on the ground that it is just an holdout method:

> ... If we apply the holdout method enough times (say 20 times for a
> 95% confidence level), false positives are no longer unlikely: They
> are expected. The more times we apply holdout, the more likely an
> invalid strategy will pass the test, which will then be published as a
> single-trial outcome ...

But publishing the results as a single-trial outcome is a misuse of Cross Validation. One should publish the average OOS performance of the K trials. So Bailey and De Prado don't have a point there. Cross Validation does solve the problem of backtest overfitting.

Am I missing something?

Comment: CV is usually abused to become an equivalent of in sample diagnostics. It can help with overfitting when done properly but it doesn’t “solve “ the problem

Comment: @Aksakal thank you, could you elaborate a bit more on "helps but does not solve"? By "solve" I meant that CV correctly estimates the OOS performance. What would be a more desirable outcome that correctly estimating the OOS performance?

Comment: CV estimates cross validation performance when done properly. Can it “correctly” estimate it? In social sciences it is a big fat question. Unless you control regressors it is easy to overestimate oos performance with cv

Answer (score 8):

*If* they publish information about all K trials, then you're right. But the author's point is that that's not typical practice. Typical practice is to not disclose that information, and it amounts to p-hacking where the statistical power of the test differs to what's being advertised.